# Why do new instances of controller have the same object_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    p self.class.object_id
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    p self.class.object_id
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Rails creates a new instance of controller per request, so I supposed them to have different object ids. However, `self.class.object_id` returns the same value within `new` and `create` actions. Why is that the case?

Comment: It does not logically follow that two controller instances would have different object ids. Given enough time span between the two requests for the first one to be garbage collected, it only logically follows that the **probability** of the two controller instances having the same object ids is low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `self.class.object_id`, you are asking the `object_id` of your **class** `ArticlesController`, not **instance**. Of course, they will be the same.

Try `self.object_id` or just `object_id`, and you will see that they are different.

Comment: `object_id` is enough. `self` is not needed anymore (It was necessary when calling `class`).

Answer (score 0):

Because the referent of `self` is an object of `ArticlesController`, when you started the server, `ArticlesController` is assigned an `object_id`. When you call it in context of the class, it returns the same `object_id` each time.

Comment: Hi, @Herminio,
Every time the browser makes a request to ArticlesController the new instance of ArticlesController with the same object_id is created - is this what you are saying?

Comment: I tried to make the least minimum change to your answer to make it grammatical and to make sense, but it is still not clear what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

In actions new and create, the object has not changed.

> self.class

The same number will be returned on all calls to object_id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id.[[Object_id]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-object_id)